# Transpose cell data into separate rows

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I wanted to see if there was a formula or something that I could do to get something like this accomplished in Google Sheets.

Table 1 is the input I am getting
Table 2 is the output I want to generate on a separate sheet

[image: Example Picture]

I am trying to use output I get from a Google form into a Google sheet and create a CSV to import into Google Groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B, ","))<>"", "♦"&SPLIT(B2:B, ",")&
 REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(@.*)")&"♣"&A2:A, )),,999^99)),,999^99), "♦")), "♣")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks so much! I am going to try and break this down so I can learn how it all works. But for now I put it in a separate sheet and I'll pull that into the sheet I am using for import.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, I ran into a hiccup. What if some of the groups have full emails in them due to a second domain. So lets say B2 had group1, group2, group3@domain2.com.

Comment: I imagine you will get: group3@domain2.com@company.com in which case you could apply REGEXEXTRACT to get rid off the "extra stuff"